# Issues in isset and function calls

Tags: php

This is the code below. I need the answer as set using this function call `newa` outside of the function.  I only get not set.

```
<?php
$home=1;
newa();
function newa(){
if (isset($home)) {

    echo "set";
}else{
    echo "not set";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thank you guys ..... the problem i needed to solve could not be done using if(isset($var)) ...... it was solved using if() only ,  sorry for the pattern i choose above, it had to be demonstrated in such a way... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please code it like this:

```
<?php
$home=1;
newa($home);
function newa($home){
if (isset($home)) {

  echo "set";
}else{
echo "not set";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to pass variable which is $home to function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php
function newa($home = null) {
    if (isset($home)) {
        echo 'set';
    } else {
        echo 'not set';
    }
}
?>
```

and Call function:

```
<?php
newa(5);
?>
```

Result:

```
set
```

or:

```
<?php
newa();
?>
```

result:

```
not set
```